# Favourite Button in UITableview (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

For my application I created a custom UITableView that also includes a button. I want to use this Button as a "mark as favourite"-Button.

Therefore I wrote this into the swift-File for my UITableViewCell:

```
@IBAction func markedButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    var objectToBeAdded: myStruct = data(data1: test, data2: test)
    if objectIsInArray(list: firmeninformation){
        markedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star blanc"), for: UIControlState.normal)}

    else{
        markedButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "star marked"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        favArray.append(firmeninformation)
    }
}
```

I don't think this is the best way to do it because if I filtern my TableView the position of the "marked as favourite" Cells stays the same. So if I mark the first Cell and then filter my TableView, the first Cell is always "marked as favourite". Any suggestions for a better solution?

Comment: Does every cell need to have favourite button ? If so then create a custom cell and let the cell contain the favourite button. In `tableView:cellForRowAt:` read from your model (array or some data source) and set the favourite button highlighted or not. In your cell set the normal and highlighted image for the button

Comment: Yes, every Cell should have a favourite Button. I already created a TableViewCell that includes a UIButton. But how can I adress a function (like "set highlighted Image") from a specific Cell.

Comment: If the whole cell can be tapped to mark as favourite then you can identify the cell tapped from `tableView:didSelectRowAt`, otherwise use a target and selector for the button. In the selector the button pressed would be passed as an argument.  In the function, identify the indexPath of the button pressed by `let location = button.convert(button.frame, to: tableView)` and then `let indexPath = tableView.indexPathsForRows(in: location)?.first`

Comment: ok thank you, I will try that out

Answer (score 0):

The best way up to your project, so I just recommend you should custom a UIButton to make it handling state itself.